# IFX standard Java Implementation

Tags: java, message, finance

I have task about financial data exchange framework `IFX` (http://www.ifxforum.org/). As I understand IFX is protocol which describes message formats about financial data, but I can not understand how to use this protocol. I have googled but no result
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading the WSDL and schemas, that would give you more insight.
http://www.ifxforum.org/standards/wswg#downloads
they are supposedly available to the public free of charge, nevertheless I haven't been able to download them.

This framework might be helpful to interpret the messages: http://ifx-framework.sourceforge.net/